# Is the response returned same as the request passed in Django?

Tags: python, html, django

I have a question about the HttpRequest and HttpResponse
consider the following scenerio:

```
def articles_cookies(request):
language = 'en-us'
session_language = 'en-us'

if 'lang' in request.COOKIES:
    language = request.COOKIES['lang']

return render_to_response('articles.html',
                          {'articles':Article.objects.all(),
                           'language':language})

def language(request,language='en-us'):
    response = HttpResponse('setting language to %s' % language)
    response.set_cookie('lang',language)
    return response
```

which is in the views.py in Django.
Is the response returned by the language same as the request passed into the articles_cookies function? because i can access the cookies in the request.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question "Is the response returned by the language same as the request passed into the articles_cookies function" doesn't make sense. A response is different from a request. Requests are sent from the client (browser) to the server. Responses are sent (in response) from the server to the client. Responses can contain set-cookie headers. Browsers store cookies. Requests contain cookie headers. Please try to ask a question that makes sense :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No they aren't the same object.

The response is returned to the browser after being serialized as HTTP response. This HTTP response can contain a Set-Cookie header which instructs the browser to send back the given Cookie when making subsequent requests.

At the next requests, the browser sends the new request with a Cookie header and Django then extracts that header into a new request object.